# Как сделать, чтобы git rebase --rebase-merges сохранял решения merge коммитов?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Когда делаю git rebase --rebase-merges, git меня просит разрешать конфликты, которые уже и так решены. Как сказать ему, чтобы он брал решения из оригинальных merge-коммитов?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere

Comment: правильно ли я понял, что нужно просто вызывать эту команду на каждом конфликте, а потом вызывать git rebase --continue ?

Comment: я проверил, rerere не работает