# Как объединить последовательные коммиты с одинаковыми именами?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

Представьте себе такой git-репозиторий:

[image: git graph]

Как видно, что в таком git-репозитории есть две группы коммитов, которые имеют одинаковые имена и идут последовательно:

- сделал фичу A
- сделал фичу A
- сделал фичу B
- сделал фичу B
- сделал фичу B

Как сделать команду `git filter-branch` такой, чтобы она объединила такие коммиты?

В результате я хочу получить это:
[image: git graph]

Я не хочу потерять изменения. Суммарные изменения должны попасть в объединённые коммиты.

Это лишь пример, на практике в git-репозитории около 15к коммитов, в которых такие повторения встречаются до 50 коммитов подряд. Так что мне нужна такая команда `git filter-branch`, которая будет действовать "по правилу". Я не могу знать заранее какие коммиты нужно будет объединить, потому что их очень много.

Comment: `git rebase -i`. Вообще на будущее посмотрите флаг fixup или squash у git commit

Comment: Сколько наблюдаю за вашими вопросами здесь про Git, всё очевиднее становится, что Git вы как-то совсем неправильно используете (страдают процессы). Может начнёте с устранения реальной проблемы?

Comment: @0andriy я душевнобольной, не обращайте внимание

Comment: @0andriy если у вас есть замечания, пожалуйста пишите их более предметно. Пример *"наблюдаю за вашими комментариями здесь, всё очевиднее становится, что комментарии вы как-то совсем неправильно используете (страдают процессы). Может начнёте с устранения реальной проблемы?"* - как видите, слов много, а смысла - ноль.

Comment: @Kromster, если вы не видите смысла, это не значит, что его там нет. Специально «разжую» тут. Когда в репозитории 15тыс изменений, которые сделаны тяп-ляп, то проблема не в VCS, не в merge конфликтах, а в **процессах** работы с этим репозиторием (workflow).

Comment: @0andriy вот так гораздо лучше, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужен интерактивный rebase.

Команде нужно передать диапазон комитов, которые вы можете, при желании, изменить, слить, удалить, разбить комит на несколько:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~6
```

В результате выполнения, откроется редактор который покажет вам историю комитов, с подсказками какие операции возможны:

```
pick f7f3f6d git init
pick 310154e feature A
pick a5f4a0d feature A
pick ffaabbd fix
pick a5fbb0d feature B
pick b5f4a03 feature B
pick f5fea00 feature B

# Rebase 710f0f8..a5f4a0d onto 710f0f8
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup <commit> = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec <command> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# b, break = stop here (continue rebase later with 'git rebase --continue')
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
```

Теперь комиты, которые хотите оставить не трогаете, т.е. действие в первой колонке должно быть `pick` - взять как есть, а для тех, которые нужно слить в предыдущие отбрасывая их собственное сообщение, меняете действие на `fixup`:

```
pick f7f3f6d git init
pick 310154e feature A
fixup a5f4a0d feature A
pick ffaabbd fix
pick a5fbb0d feature B
fixup b5f4a03 feature B
fixup f5fea00 feature B
```

и сохраняете и [закрываете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437417/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-vi-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-vim) редактор.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Насколько я знаю, rebase требует заново решать merge конфликты. У меня в git 15к коммитов, это будет нереально заново их решать. Поэтому я ожидал решения с filter-branch

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук на вашей картинке нет никаких merge

Comment: в вопросе я изначально написал про 15к коммитов и про `git filter-branch`

Comment: Про merge конфликты в вопросе стоит упомянуть. 15к комитов сами по себе это не большая проблема. Текст из `git rebase -i` можно обработать скриптом. А вот конфликты - это проблема.

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук, ну добавьте `--rebase-merges`, в чём проблема?

Comment: @0andriy в том, что эта опция не решает конфликты. я даже когда-то задавал вопрос по этому поводу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1202515/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-git-rebase-rebase-merges-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%bb-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-merge-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2

Answer (score 1):

Оставлю решение, которое получилось у меня.

Допустим, git-репозиторий находится в директории `/path/to/git/`.
Создаем копию этого репозитория во временной директории:

```
cp -r /path/to/git /tmp/git-original
```

Позже напишу, зачем это нужно.

Далее нужно создать такой скрипт по пути `/tmp/check-skip-commit.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

CURRENT_DIRECTORY=`pwd`;
GIT_COMMIT="$1"
GIT_ORIGINAL_PATH="$2"

cd $GIT_ORIGINAL_PATH
CHILDREN=`git rev-list --all --not $GIT_COMMIT^@ --children | grep "^$GIT_COMMIT" | sed -E "s/[^ ]+ |$GIT_COMMIT//"`
cd $CURRENT_DIRECTORY

if [ -z "$CHILDREN" ]
then
   exit 1
fi

if [[ $CHILDREN == *" "* ]]
then
   exit 1
fi

cd $GIT_ORIGINAL_PATH
COMMIT_MESSAGE=`git log -1 --pretty=format:%s $GIT_COMMIT`
CHILD_MESSAGE=`git log -1 --pretty=format:%s $CHILDREN`
cd $CURRENT_DIRECTORY

if [ "$COMMIT_MESSAGE" = "$CHILD_MESSAGE" ]
then
   exit 0
fi

exit 1
```

И делаем его исполняемым:

```
chmod 777 /tmp/check-skip-commit.sh
```

Этот скрипт принимает первым параметром hash коммита, а вторым - путь к директории git-репозитория.

Этот скрипт проверяет, нужно ли пропустить коммит или нет. Для тех коммитов, у которых имеется только один дочерний коммит с таким же именем, скрипт вернет exit code равный `1`, а иначе `0`. Пропуск коммита по сути означает его удаление, а изменения коммита будут перенесены в его дочерний коммит, что по сути является объединением двух коммитов.

Дальше осталось запустить процесс, переходим в директорию с репозиторием:

```
cd /path/to/git/
```

И запускам команду:

```
git filter-branch -f --commit-filter '
    if /tmp/check-skip-commit.sh $GIT_COMMIT /tmp/git-original
    then
        skip_commit "$@";
    else
        git commit-tree "$@";
    fi' -- --all
```

В этой команде используется наш скрипт `/tmp/check-skip-commit.sh`. Вторым аргументом для него передается путь к копии репозитория `/tmp/git-original`.
Это нужно для того, чтобы скрипт мог получить имя коммита и имя дочернего коммита. Использовать оригинальный репозиторий `/path/to/git/` не получится, потому что он уже в процессе перезаписи (по крайней мере у меня так не работает, выдает ошибки).

---

Можно усложнить условие объединения. Для этого в скрипте `/tmp/check-skip-commit.sh` можно изменить это условие под себя:

```
if [ "$COMMIT_MESSAGE" = "$CHILD_MESSAGE" ]
then
   exit 0
fi
```